# c++: how to define function that accpets all the sub-class of a speciic class

Tags: c++, inheritance

Let me write the relation that `A` is a sub-class of `B` by `A < B`. Suppose there is a relation `A < B < C` between three classes.

Now, what I want to do is to define a function/class-method that can take argument of all `A`, `B` and `C` (all the sub-class of `A`). Is it possible? and if so, how can I do this?

**EDIT: MOTIVATION**
The motivation of this is as follows:
Let say I want to solve a maze. The solver function `solve_maze` takes a `Maze` and solve the maze. By default, `is_obstacle_free` is set to return `true` always. This means that default maze is the empty space.

What I want to do is, enabling the user to define their custom `CustomMaze` by inheriting the `Maze` class if they want. User can change the shape of the maze by tweaking the `is_obstacle_free` function. Maybe, another user want to define class `CustomMaze2` inheriting from `CustomMaze`.

If I can define `solve_maze` function that accept any sub-type of `Maze`, we can avoid defining `solve_maze` anytime users added a new maze type.

```cpp
class Maze
{
   virtual bool is_obstacle_free(Point p){
       return true;
   }
};

class CustomMaze : public Maze
{
  bool is_obstacle_free(Point p) override;
};

void solve_maze(Space s, Solution& sol){
   \\ call a lot of is_obstacle_free inside
}
```

Comment: Your parameter has to be a reference or pointer instead. However, you still can only access the members of that class type that you used as a parameter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

Comment: TL;DR version: They have not been cast. `sample` takes an `A` by value, so it copies the given argument into `a` and since `a` cannot hold a `B` or `C` but both are implicitly convertible to `A`, `a` is a new object that leaves out any `B`- or C`-ness.

Comment: Change `void sample(A a);` -> `void sample(A & a);`

Comment: Polymorphism may also come in handy here ([example](https://godbolt.org/z/EYcG1854M)). Please describe what you want to do with the argument in `sample()`.

Comment: If you want to learn C++, I recommend getting a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). The language is probably too complicated to learn by asking questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: @TedLyngmo OK, I write the motivation again. without casting of not is actually not the point here. I should have made the motivation clear.

Comment: @orematasaburo You described nothing about what you expect to do with the argument inside `sample`. Did you look at my example? Also, I don't know anything about the julia language.

Comment: You can use templates and specify which types it can accept.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I editted the motivation.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Rather, the language is too complicated to learn by reading book, I guess. Anyway, I edited the question quite a lot.

Comment: @orematasaburo Looks close to my example but you missed making it a reference. [Look here](https://godbolt.org/z/fTKjdjWc4)

Comment: It is still complicated, but a good book will teach you to ask better questions.

Comment: Your motivation can be simplified to this sentence: "I want bog-standard polymorphism". In C++ you get bog-standard polymorphism by using a pointer or a reference to a base class.

Comment: A good book can speed the learning of the language enormously. Watershed book for me was Effective C++. Probably a bit dated now, but at the time it was the bomb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void sample(A& a);
```

will accept anything that derives from `A`, but `sample` will only use `a` as if it were an `A` object (without casting).

With templates, you can do this without casting:

```
template <typename T>
void sample(T& t)
{
  static_assert(std::is_base_of<A,T>::value, "T must be derived from A");
  // T is whatever sample was called with.
}
```